# Bloquear semanas pasadas en input week

Tags: html5, date, entrada

quiero bloquear las semanas pasadas a la actual en un input type week para que no sean seleccionables.

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda!
saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el atributo `min` para establecer la semana mínima prácticamente no la pueden seleccionar. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
<input type="week" name="semana" min="2014-W01" max="2018-W16" value="2018-W15">
```

También esta el atributo max ;).